# Variable-pitch font has stopped rendering correctly

Tags: fonts, customize

For some reason, variable-pitch fonts have stopped rendering correctly.  They previously worked fine, but something seems to have changed (though nothing in my .emacs has changed).

I am using OS X 10.10.3 and Emacs installed thru homebrew.  From the startup screen:

> This is GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0, NS apple-appkit-1347.57).

Question: how do I fix this to make variable-pitch work again?

Here are a couple pictures to explain:

[image: Emacs startup screen]

The Emacs startup screen uses both fixed-width and variable-width fonts, and the ones that inherit from variable-pitch are rendered incorrectly.

[image: Examples of several fixed- and variable-width fonts]

I found a [script on EmacsWiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GoodFonts#toc15) to test several fonts at once.  Again, fixed-width fonts render correctly, but variable-width fonts do not.

Comment: What operating system are you running Emacs on?

Comment: @legoscia OS X, sorry, I thought it was in the screenshot.  I'll add some info in the question.